# Windows software RAID 1: how to identify which drive failed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid

I have a Windows Server 2008 set as RAID 1. Recentely it changed to "Failed Redudancy".

How do I know which disk failed?

Should I try to resync the array before replacing the disk? If so, what is the correct procedure in this case?

Here is an image showing the current status:

[image: Image showing the current status]

Comment: Have you checked the event logs ? They should specify which hard drive had errors.

Comment: Ok, just checked it. I found some events with id 11 and message "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort0".

Comment: *IDE*? How old is this hardware? Regardless, you now have your answer as to which drive it is...

Comment: Actually, both are SATA disks. I don't know why it's showing as \Device\Ide\IdePort0.

Comment: They may be set to ATA compatibility mode in the BIOS, I think that makes them appear to be IDE to the O/S.

Answer (score 1):

Check the event logs.
The events with `ID 11` will specify which port the device that is having issues is on.